# Calling a calculation that is stored in an array (js)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and I want to do a calculation that is stored IN the array.

For example:

```
var Count = 0;
var Test = [0,Count++,0,0];
```

Inside a function I want to increase the variable Count by doing something like:

```
function Debug(){
    Test[1];
}
```

I have tried many variation of this and i have managed to:

- Get Count increased by one when the array is declared or
- Do nothing
- Create a new fuction for each array cell, which is really time consuming for what i 'm trying to do. I would like something faster/easier.

I want the code to NOT run when i declare the array but run when i call the specific array cell, if possible without declaring new functions the whole time.

Comment: JS, what he did to you? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seemed to be looking for syntactic simplicity.  And I don't see a way to grant you that.  But there is a way to run a function on field access.  So this might do what you want, at the expense of initial set-up complexity:

```
var Test = [0, "replace me", 0, 0];

Object.defineProperties(Test, {
  1: {get: (() => {let count = -1; return () => ++count})()}
});

Test[0]; //=> 0
Test[1]; //=> 0
Test[2]; //=> 0
Test[3]; //=> 0
Test[0]; //=> 0
Test[1]; //=> 1
Test[2]; //=> 0
Test[3]; //=> 0
Test[1]; //=> 2
Test[1]; //=> 3
Test[1]; //=> 4
```

If the ES6 fat-arrow syntax is confusing, this is the equivalent of:

```
Object.defineProperties(Test, {
  1: {get: (function() {
    let count = -1; 
    return function() {
      return ++count;
    };
  })()}
});
```

Comment: Bingo! I avoided the time consuming initial setup by a copy-paste of my array with opposite signs (works fine on my project) and everything works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to do this a bit differently. You need to wrap the `Count` increment in its own function:

```
var Count = 0;
var Test=[0, function() { Count++ }, 0, 0];
```

And then call the function:

```
function Debug() {
    Test[1]();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
var count = 0,
      arr = [0,"count++",0,0],
  runItem = Function("return " + arr[1]);
runItem(); // <- 0
runItem(); // <- 1
```